# Counter With Frequency divider is not incrementing

Tags: verilog, flip-flop

The following code is written for an asynchronous counter. The program compiles fine but the counter value doesn't increment after `1`. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
//TOP

module CounterWithDivider(clk,reset,temp,q);

input clk,reset;
output [3:0]q;
output reg [3:0]temp;

reg [3:0]clkDivider;

TFF a(clkDivider,clk,reset,q[0]);
TFF b(clkDivider,q[0],reset,q[1]);
TFF c(clkDivider,q[1],reset,q[2]);
TFF d(clkDivider,q[2],reset,q[3]);

always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)
begin

if(~reset || clkDivider==12)
  clkDivider<=0;

else

if(clk)
begin

 clkDivider<=clkDivider+1;
 temp<=clkDivider;

end

end

endmodule
```

// T flip flop

```
module TFF(clkDivider,clk,reset,q);

input clk,reset;
input [3:0]clkDivider;
output reg q;

always @(posedge clk or negedge reset)
begin

if(~reset)
  q<=0;

else

if(clkDivider==11)
  q<=1;


end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

A T-FlipFlop, or toggle flop should toggle its output when enabled, you just have:

```
if(clkDivider==11)
  q<=1;
```

Replace  `q<=1` with `q<=~q` to make it toggle when enabled.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, this is an asynchrous counter.  The reason your Verilog simulation is not doing what you want is that `TFF` instance `b` is trying to sample its data input (`clkDivider`) using a different clock signal.  `clkDivider` is clocked by signal `clk`, but you are trying to sample it using a different clock signal (`q[0]`).

You need to either find a way to synchronize the clkDivider signal into each of the other 3 clock domains, or use a fully synchronous design.